# Practicing add/sub/mul two complex number by python

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I am trying to add/sub/multiply two complex numbers. Terminal said there is a SyntaxError at "ComplexCompute".
What does that mean? Thanks.

```
Class ComplexCompute (object):
    def __init__(self, realPart, imagPart):
        self.realPart = realPart
        self.imagPart = imagPart
    def __add__(self, other)
        r1 = self.imagPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = self.imagPart
        resultR = r1+r2
        resultI = i1+i2
        result = complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result
    def __sub__(self, other)
        r1 = self.imagPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = self.imagPart
        resultR = r1-r2
        resultI = i1-i2
        result = complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result
    def __mul__(self, other)
        r1 = self.imagPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = self.imagPart
        resultR = (r1*r2-i1*i2)
        resultI = (r1*i2+r2*i1)
        result = complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result    
c1 = ComplexCompute(2,3)
c2 = ComplexCompute(1,4)
print c1+c2
print c1-c2
print c1*c2
```

I edited the name of Class in some method.
But the terminal showed:

> <**main**.Complex object at 0x1005d8b90>
>
> <**main**.Complex object at 0x1005d8b90>
>
> <**main**.Complex object at 0x1005d8b90>

```
class Complex (object):
    def __init__(self, realPart, imagPart):
        self.realPart = realPart
        self.imagPart = imagPart

    def __add__(self, other):
        r1 = self.imagPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = other.imagPart 
        resultR = r1+r2
        resultI = i1+i2
        result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result

    def __sub__(self, other):
        r1 = self.imagPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = other.imagPart
        resultR = r1-r2
        resultI = i1-i2
        result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result

    def __mul__(self, other):
        r1 = self.imagPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = other.imagPart
        resultR = (r1*r2-i1*i2)
        resultI = (r1*i2+r2*i1)
        result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result   

c1 = Complex(2,3)
c2 = Complex(1,4)

print c1+c2
print c1-c2
print c1*c2
```

the **str** method: (which not works)

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%d+(%d)j'&(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
```

Latest version:
(Terminal shows SyntaxError 'return' outside function in **div** method)

```
class Complex (object):
    def __init__(self, realPart, imagPart):
    self.realPart = realPart
    self.imagPart = imagPart            

    def __str__(self):
        if type(self.realPart) == int and type(self.imagPart) == int:
            if self.imagPart >=0:
                return '%d+%di'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
            elif self.imagPart <0:
                return '%d%di'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
        else:
            if self.imagPart >=0:
                return '%f+%fi'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
            elif self.imagPart <0:
               return '%f%fi'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)

    def __add__(self, other):
        r1 = self.realPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = other.imagPart
        resultR = r1+r2
        resultI = i1+i2
        result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result

    def __sub__(self, other):
        r1 = self.realPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = other.imagPart
        resultR = r1-r2
        resultI = i1-i2
        result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result   

    def __mul__(self, other):
        r1 = self.realPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = other.imagPart
        resultR = (r1*r2-i1*i2)
        resultI = (r1*i2+r2*i1)
        result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result

    def __div__(self, other):
        r1 = self.realPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = other.imagPart
        resultR = float(float(r1*r2+i1*i2)/float(r2*r2+i2*i2))
        resultI = float(float(r2*i1-r1*i2)/float(r2*r2+i2*i2))
        result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result

c1 = Complex(2,3)
c2 = Complex(1,4)

print c1+c2
print c1-c2
print c1*c2
print c1/c2
```

Comment: Your indentation looks incorrect. Is this how your actual code is indented?

Comment: Capital C in class and space before the parenthesis?

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- I doubt that the space is an issue, but the capital letter definitely is (see my answer)

Comment: @mgilson Good call (and sorry, didn't see your post until after I commented :) )

Comment: Also, you do realize that the capability to multiply, add, and subtract complex numbers is already builtin, right? You can do so with the complex number type which you use in your return values for `__add__`, `__sub__`, and `__mul__`.

Comment: @lavitanien -- You shouldn't keep correcting the errors on your post for a few reasons.  1) it makes it so that the text/title of the post no longer matches the actual content.  2) it makes the post virtually useless for others who come along and might have the same problem you did (they can no longer see what your problem was!) and least importantly, 3) It makes those of us who answered look stupid because now our answers don't address the question whatsoever.

Comment: @mgilson Sorry for that. I've made the code back to where it was when I posted the question.

Comment: @lavitanien -- Thanks.  I (and others who stumble upon this post from google searches) appreciate it :).  Is your problem solved now?  Feel free to accept an answer if it is.

Comment: @mgilson Sorry for some stupid behavior in this post. (I'm not a developer but trying to learn to code. I'm not familiar with some habits of developers.)

Comment: @lavitanien -- It's really not a problem.  (Don't worry about it at all).  Since I've been around SO (a lot) for a while now, I've gotten used to how things are done around here -- And I'm happy to help bring you up to speed on that as well.  The better the questions (and answers!) the better the site :).  Good luck with your coding!

Comment: @mgilson There seems to be one more small problem regarding to the name of class which I've posted in the question. Thank you!

Comment: @lavitanien -- you need to add a `__str__` method which will return the string that gets printed.

Comment: @mgilson Should that be something like this? (also pasted above)  def __str__(self):
    return '%d+(%d)j'&(self.realPart, self.imagPart)

Comment: @lavitanien -- Super close:  `return '%d+(%d)j'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)` (`%` instead of `&`)

Comment: @mgilson I've added the __str__ method as above.

Now the terminal shows SyntaxError: 'return' outside function in my __div__ method. Could you help with that? Thanks.

Comment: I can't see why you would get a SyntaxError there.  My best guess is that you're mixing tabs and spaces (don't do that ;).  You can call your script with `python -tt scriptname.py` to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than your indentation errors (which I assume is due to copy/paste issues), You want it to say `class` instead of `Class`  (Note the lower case `c`)

Also, you are missing `:` after some of your methods:

```
def __add__(self,other):
                      #^ NEED THIS
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an indentation error.  You need the methods to be indented like so:

```
class ComplexCompute(object):

  def method(self):
    # blah blah

  def another_method(self):
    # hello
```

---

On an unrelated note, watch out for the various bugs where you have another `self` that should be `other`.  They are in each of your methods implementations.  And also you have several times `r1 = self.imagPart` where you probably meant `r1 = self.realPart`.

Comment: That would raise an `IndentationError`, not a `SyntaxError`.  Indentation is probably due to copy/paste into SO

Comment: @mgilson, he'll have that problem as soon as he reruns it.

Comment: True, I assumed they were saying about a "syntax error" not a `SyntaxError`  :)